# .DSA, .SF, and .RSA files not getting removed from jar file even after mentioning it exclude in the POM.xml

Tags: jar

While creating jar file in IntelliJ Idea, .DSA, .SF were getting created.

I searched for solutions and got from StackOverflow only. I applied the solutions and added the plugins into the POM.xml. Even after adding the plugins, the jar file is still creating .dsa and .sf files.

The snippet of code to exclude the .dsa and .sf files is as follows:

```
<build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>shade</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <transformers>
                                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                        <mainClass>com.sdf.DSABlocker</mainClass>
                                    </transformer>
                                </transformers>
                                <filters>
                                    <filter>
                                        <artifact>*:*:*:</artifact>
                                        <excludes>
                                            <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                            <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                            <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                        </excludes>
                                    </filter>
                                </filters>
                                <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                                <shadedClassifierName>standalone</shadedClassifierName>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
```

What steps shall I do so that those files will get excluded?